# How to make a Mixed Linear Model with two fixed effects and one random effect in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

New to coding so I'm not sure how to even go about doing this. 
I have a df that looks something like this:

```
        ID        A          B
0       1         20         4.0
1       1         24         5.0
2       2         24         0.0
3       2         9          2.0
4       3         24         1.0
5       3         24         0.0
```

I want to make a Mixed Linear model that allows me to correlate A and B to show variability within ID. A and B are my fixed effects while ID is my random effect. I want it to be so that A is dependent on B.
I have attempted to use this code in order to complete this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula("B~ A", df1, groups=df1["ID"])
result = model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

However I keep getting the invalid syntax error. 
I was also wondering how I could plot this on a scatter plot, because I would like to find correlation between A and B based on the slope of each line for each ID.

Comment: Can't replicate your invalid syntax error... Works perfectly fine on my computer.

Comment: @xyzjayne not sure why it didnt work but I got it to run... literally spent hours trying to get that to work